# convert BITMAP to HBITMAP

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

If I have a `BITMAP` named `bitmap`, how to I convert this into an HBITMAP?

So far I have tried:

```
HBITMAP hbm = (HBITMAP)&bitmap; //doesn't work

HANDLE hand = &bitmap;
HBITMAP hbm = hand; //doesn't work

CImage cim;
cim.Attach(&bitmap);
HBITMAP hbm = cim.Detach(); //definitely doesn't work

CBitmap cbm;
cbm.Attach(bitmap);
CImage cim;
cim.Attach(cbm.Detach());
HBITMAP hbm = cbm.Detach(); //desperate I know, horribly failed
```

There has got to be some easy, one line way to do it but I just can't find it.  Can I get some help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Call [`CreateBitmapIndirect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183486.aspx) passing your `BITMAP`. Hey presto, an `HBITMAP` is returned.

For what it's worth, a good way to look for the answer yourself is to go to the MSDN topic describing [`BITMAP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183371.aspx). Scroll down to the bottom of the page and look at the *See Also* section. The most important functions that use the type will be listed there, and indeed `CreateBitmapIndirect` is there. That's always a useful way of finding out what can be done with any particular Win32 type.